# Save image to DB in unit test doesn't work with type binary in CakePHP 2

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, fixtures, cakephp-2.x

Here is the fixture code:

```
class UploadfileFixture extends CakeTestFixture {

/**
 * Fields
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $fields = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'key' => 'primary'),
        'data' => array('type' => 'binary', 'null' => false, 'default' => null),
        'path' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'charset' => 'utf8'),
...
```

As you can see I'm using `binary` type for `BLOB` in `data` column as specified in [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html).

On save method:

```
 $file['data'] = @file_get_contents($uri);
 ...
 $model_file->save($file);
```

I'm getting this message when trying to save 151K image:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'data' at row 1
```

Comment: As a side note: You should not store such images in the DB, those are not made for this, some file system should be used instead and only the link/path should be stored in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that you are using MySQL, which means that your `BLOB` type column will be limited to

> *L* + 2 bytes, where *L* < 2<sup>16</sup>

**http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html#idm140456796731584**

ie, 64k, which your 151k exceeds by far.

By default CakePHPs fixtures only support `binary`, which will map to `blob` no matter what. You can however add custom column definitions, or modify existing ones via the `Mysql::$columns` property. You can do so by for example

### using an extended datasource

**app/Model/Datasource/Database/AppMysql.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('Mysql', 'Model/Datasource/Database');

class AppMysql extends Mysql
{
    public function __construct($config, $autoConnect)
    {
        $this->columns['mediumbinary'] = array('name' => 'mediumblob');
        parent::__construct($config, $autoConnect);
    }
}
```

**app/Config/database.php**

```
public $test = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/AppMysql',
    // ...
);
```

**Your fixture**

```
public $fields = array(
    // ...
    'data' => array('type' => 'mediumbinary', 'null' => false, 'default' => null),
    // ...
);
```

### or by modifying the datasource on the fly

for example in that specific fixture, like

```
public function init()
{
    $source = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig);
    $source->columns['mediumbinary'] = array('name' => 'mediumblob');

    parent::init();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer. I tested it and it does work perfectly.